# Add class for parent of parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

how can I add a class in a drop dowwn menu on click when child of parent of parent is clicked.
This is my html:

```
<ul id="FirstLevel">
    <li><a href="#">FirstLevel</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">FirstLevel</a>
        <ul class="secondLevel">
            <li><a href="#">SecondLevel</a></li>
                   <ul class="LastLevel">
                         <li><a href="#">LastLevel</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#">LastLevel</a></li>
                   </ul>
            <li><a href="#">SecondLevel</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">SecondLevel</a></li>

        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">FirstLevel</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">FirstLevel</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">FirstLevel</a></li>
</ul
```

So what I need is that; `onclick` on `LastLevel` or `SecondLevel` of my menu I want to add a class via jQuery on `FirstLevel` `li` and to remove that class when another sub menu is selected.

I've tried this but is not really working:

```
$('#firstUl').find('li').click(function(){ //removing the previous selected menu state $('#firstUl').find('li').removeClass('active'); //is this element from the second level menu? if($(this).closest('ul').hasClass('lastLevel')){ $(this).parents('li').parents('li').addClass('menuActive'); //this is a parent element }else{ $(this).addClass('menuActive'); } });
```

Thank you.

Comment: please show us your javascript code

Comment: just update it in your question. not in the comment

Comment: so exactly which li should have the class ?

Comment: @Parthik Gosar first li

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give your FirstLevel `<li>'s` a class, it'd make it much easier to target the correct element:

```
<li class="first-level"><a href="#">FirstLevel</a></li>
```

Then attach a click handler to all child `<li>'s`:

```
$('li.first-level li').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // prevent the link from being followed
  $(this).closest('li.first-level').toggleClass('yourClass') // 
         .siblings('li.first-level').removeClass('yourClass');
});
```

#### [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3FLVS/1/)

Comment: interesting but this give me a class for all ul, li's from menu :| I nedd that class only for first level li's.

Comment: It does only add the class to the first level `<li>`, the reason you see the style being 'applied' to the children is because they are all contained within that first level `<li>`

Comment: You *could* add the class to the anchor, [see here](http://jsfiddle.net/3FLVS/6/)

Answer (score 1):

This does all the things you want:

```
$("ul.secondLevel a").click(function () {
    $("#FirstLevel>li").removeClass("blue");
    $(this).parents("ul.secondLevel").parent().addClass("blue");
});
```

Check here: http://jsfiddle.net/c4dTK/

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution :

```
$('.secondLevel li a').click(function (e) {
    $('#FirstLevel > li').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).parents('.secondLevel').parent().addClass('selected');
})
```

Comment: @BalintBako Sorry I didn't see your response before, It was merely a coincidence that we both gave responses along the same lines. But if you still feel that I copied I can delete my response. :)

Comment: I don't really mind actually :) if it is not a copy-paste that is

Answer (score 0):

As your first level list has been given an Id, you could just find the element using a selector as follows:

```
$(".secondLevel a").click(function () {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#FirstLevel li").addClass("newClass");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
jQuery(this).parent('ul').addClass('yourClass');
```

Or:

```
jQuery(this).parents('ul').addClass('yourClass');
```

Answer (score 0):

here goes another answer

```
var test= $('li li,li li li')
console.log(test)
            test.click(function(){
   $(this).parents('ul').closest('li').addClass('kaka');
});
```

**[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GCVAQ/4/)**

Comment: this add a class to all second ul LI need to add a class only for first level li

Comment: so, what seems to be a problem ? it selects first `li`, or it's not?